# Is it possible to atomically change mount device in Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, mount-point

Is it possible to change what device is mounted to a mount point atomically, so at no moment of time mount point can be observed empty? Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$ mkdir /point
$ mkdir /device1 /device2
$ echo 1 > /device1/text
$ echo 2 > /device2/text
$ mount --bind /device1 /point
$ # do some kind of magic to get /device2 mounted at /point and /device1 unmounted
```

Technically, I can ignore previous mount and mount new device on top, but kernel will keep keep record of both now, so it feels like "mount leak".

Answer (score 0):

I have run following successfully [ubuntu "20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"]:

```
/tmp# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e
mkdir -p /tmp/{point,device1,device2}
echo 1 > /tmp/device1/text
echo 2 > /tmp/device2/text
mount --bind /tmp/device1 /tmp/point
cat /tmp/point/text
mount --bind /tmp/device2 /tmp/point
cat /tmp/point/text
umount /tmp/device1
echo "Finished successfully"

/tmp# bash test.sh
1
2
Finished successfully
/tmp#
```

Comment: `umount: /tmp/device1/: not mounted.`. /device1 is not mount point.

Comment: @KAction See my update

Comment: ```+; doas bash test.sh
1
2
umount: /tmp/device1: not mounted.
Finished successfully
+; doas bash test.sh
+; which umount
/bin/umount
+; umount --version
umount from util-linux 2.37.2 (libmount 2.37.2: btrfs, namespaces, assert, debug)

Comment: Since your script does not use "set -e", I can't be sure that unmounting is successful on your machine either.

Comment: @KAction Added `set -e`. Same success.

Comment: Can you show `cat /tmp/point/text` after umount?